# Props in react seems to not be usable right away

Tags: reactjs

I have a small issue with a really simple component that doesn't display what I want.

```
const UserCards = (props) => {
  const [retrievedData, setRetrievedData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [];

    props.users.map((user) => {
      data.push(<UserCard key={user.username} user={user} />);
    });
    setRetrievedData(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.userCards}>{retrievedData && retrievedData}</div>
  );
};
```

When I refresh the page it will not display my User cards. But If I had a timeout on useEffect like this :

```
const UserCards = (props) => {
  const [retrievedData, setRetrievedData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [];
    setTimeout(function () {
      props.users.map((user) => {
        data.push(<UserCard key={user.username} user={user} />);
      });
      setRetrievedData(data);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.userCards}>{retrievedData && retrievedData}</div>
  );
};
```

Everything's fine!

I thought props were usable immediately but it seems I was wrong.

I tried to add [props] at the end of useEffect to be sure my state will be updated if props changed, but nothing...

I'm sure it's nothing but I've been struggling since yesterday!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add useEffect dependency, which will call your useEffect content every time, when dependency changed:

```
const UserCards = (props) => {
  const [retrievedData, setRetrievedData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [];

    props.users.map((user) => {
      data.push(<UserCard key={user.username} user={user} />);
    });
    setRetrievedData(data);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.userCards}>{retrievedData && retrievedData}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: As I said at the end, I already tried that but without success :(

Comment: It should. That's how hooks works. Then the problem with your props.

Comment: Do you have a working example with issue on codesandbox or something?